# how to read input as json and forward the same while using forward plugin in FluentD?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, fluentd

i am sending data from my .Net application to FluentD which in-turn is forwarded to Elastic search. Data is sent as String "{\"foo\":\"abc\"}", this data should be read as Json at FluentD level and then forward the same to Elastic Search. I tried to use Json parser & formatter in FluentD, but formatter is not supported in forward plugin and parser didn't help out either, below is the configuration i tried

```
<source>
  @type forward
  @id input_forward
</source>
<match abc.*>
  @type elasticsearch
  index_name trans
  format json
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</match>
```

I tried to Json object to FluentD but i keeps getting an error as "This operation is not supported because 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' cannot be instanciated."

How do i see the output at FluentD & Elastic Search as `"{"foo":"abc"}"` ???

Answer (score 1):

One way to circumvent this is to add a [JSON ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/json-processor.html) that will parse the message just before indexing documents.

First you need to create the ingest pipeline, so run this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/json-parser
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "json": {
        "field": "message",
        "add_to_root": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you need to modify the index settings to make sure that the above pipeline runs on each document indexation:

```
PUT trans/_settings
{
   "index.default_pipeline": "json-parser"
}
```

And then you can start FluentD and it should work automagically.

Comment: wouldn't this cause any kind of performance issues on ES??
if i run the _ingest query then i am getting an error as ```{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "[processors] required property is missing",
        "property_name" : "processors"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "[processors] required property is missing",
    "property_name" : "processors"
  },
  "status" : 400
}```

Comment: See my updated answer to fix the error... regarding the performance, try first and act after :-)

Comment: The error is fixed, thanks for that. Before your suggestions o\p was 
```"_source" : {
          "message" : "{\"foo\":\"abc\"}"
        }```
now it is ```"_source" : {
          "foo" : "abc",
          "message" : "{\"foo\":\"abc\"}"
        }``` Is it not possible to alter the message itself as ```"message":{"foo":"abc"}```

Comment: What about now?